# react js redux field array file input issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

There is an issue in file input when removing a row from the table which is a redux field array.

[image]

When deleting the first row the file input name is not changing.

[image]

table.js (FieldArray component)

```js
<td>
         <Field
          name={`${member}.file`}             
          component={UploadFile}
          id={index}                          
         />
   </td>
```

UploadFile.js

```
return (
   <div className={className} >
    <div>
      {label && <label>{label}</label>}
      <div>
        <input
          name={input.name}
          type="file"
          accept={accept}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          style={style}              
          id={`file${id}`}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <span className="input-error-msg">
      {touched &&
        ((error && <span>{error}</span>) ||
          (warning && <span>{warning}</span>))}
    </span>
  </div>
);
```

I think this issue is regarding HTML binding.

Comment: Did you use a key in your td ?

Comment: In main <tr> yes after map function

Comment: Did you use index as key? If you use index it is that reason you have this issue. You need to use an unique key

Comment: yes i used index as key.

Comment: You should use an unique id as Omar mentioned, react need to have an unique identifier, an the index will change depending the amount of items so ir you remove or modify items the index will change thus the reference to an specific item gets messed up. Use an id and if you can't use a library to generate unique ids and use them as a key.

Comment: yes, I was trying. I used Fragment before <tr> but no luck so let me get a unique key. Thanks, Omar Sy and jean182

Answer (score 0):

The issue solved by using unique id as the key instead of an index inside the map function as suggested by Omar Sy.